# ffmpeg transcode on cifs mount hangs

Tags: ffmpeg

To save some space on my NAS I plan on transcoding recorded videos (source: vuplus duo2 vdr dvb-s2 / transport streams). With a local file this works perfectly and reduces size to roughly 20% of original size:

`ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel 'warning' -c:v h264_qsv -err_detect ignore_err -i file.ts -c:v hevc_qsv -preset medium -global_quality 25 -c:a copy Processed/file.mp4`

When running the same command on a file on a NAS-mount, the process hangs after a while with the following last lines of output:

```
[vost#0:0/hevc_qsv @ 0x557c57a5aa00] Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.089439
[NULL @ 0x557c5746e3c0] ct_type:0 pic_struct:0
[vost#0:0/hevc_qsv @ 0x557c57a5aa00] Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.089439
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame= 2263 fps=264 q=-0.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:45.22 bitrate= 695.7kbits/s dup=55 drop=0 speed=5.28x    
Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>]
```

ffmpeg keeps on causing 100% load on one core even after 1 hour w/o any progress and without any data traffic. The only difference is file being saved on a disk attached to laptop (working) and the file being on a smb / cifs mount from my NAS (gets stuck at arbitrary frame). The location of the script itself does not matter. I do not experience any issues with the NAS, i.e. any other file operation is working perfectly.

The option `-err_detect` does not seem to have any influence. The connection from laptop to NAS is 1GBit/s (through some ubiquiti devices). Using hardware acceleration on decoding or encoding does not seem to have any influence. I tried several options, all get stuck at some point in time. The ffmpeg call here is just the one I favor.

These are the questions I have:

- Is this expected behaviour of ffmpeg/libav? Where to find some details?
- Are there specific cifs mount options to consider?
- Any other suggestions how to get to the root cause?

Any help highly appreciated!

Best regards

segment0287

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `ffmpeg` looses one segment due to network/NAS lag.
I'd check:

1. Sequential copy speed over network. Simple copy of file will do. See if  there are some falls or spikes in data transfer. 1Gb/s could be only 'last hop' while 'in transit' results may vary.
2. Update ffmpeg to latest version to rule out application bugs (or to add new ones :) ).
3. Try to encode exactly the same file from local drive and remotely.
4. Try different codec with NAS file. If GPU allows, I'd recommend `h264_nvenc`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the hints!
With respect to #1: checked with ```pv -pra source_file > dest_file``` and ```rsync --progress source_file dest_file``` and it has a constant rate >95MB/sec.
The files contain spaces in the filenames which caused some headaches. This I will investigate deeper.
With respect to #2: it is the ubuntu 23.10.1 ffmpeg 6.0 version - should be ok
#3 I am investigating again.
#4 can't use on intel iris xe gpu